# Why is my pdb looking so weird?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, visualization-software, vmd, pdb

I have generated the following pdb file for a polymer:

```
COMPND    MY_POLYMER
AUTHOR    SAT
ATOM       1  M1  POL 1        2.0     0.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       2  M1  POL 1        3.0     0.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       3  M1  POL 1        3.0     1.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       4  M1  POL 1        2.0     0.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       5  M1  POL 1        1.0     0.0     1.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       6  M1  POL 1        0.0     1.0     1.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       7  M1  POL 1        1.0     0.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       8  M1  POL 1        0.0     0.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM       9  M1  POL 1        1.0     1.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      10  M1  POL 1        0.0     1.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      11  M1  POL 1        0.0     1.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      12  M1  POL 1       -1.0     2.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      13  M1  POL 1        0.0     2.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      14  M1  POL 1        1.0     2.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      15  M1  POL 1        1.0     3.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      16  M1  POL 1        0.0     2.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      17  M1  POL 1        0.0     2.0     5.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      18  M1  POL 1        0.0     3.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      19  M1  POL 1        1.0     3.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      20  M1  POL 1        0.0     3.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      21  M1  POL 1       -1.0     2.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      22  M1  POL 1       -1.0     2.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      23  M1  POL 1       -1.0     1.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      24  M1  POL 1        0.0     0.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      25  M1  POL 1       -1.0     1.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      26  M1  POL 1       -1.0     1.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      27  M1  POL 1        0.0     1.0     5.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      28  M1  POL 1        1.0     2.0     5.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      29  M1  POL 1        1.0     1.0     5.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      30  M1  POL 1        2.0     0.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      31  M1  POL 1        1.0     0.0     5.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      32  M1  POL 1        2.0     1.0     5.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      33  M1  POL 1        1.0     0.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      34  M1  POL 1        0.0     0.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      35  M1  POL 1        1.0     0.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      36  M1  POL 1        1.0     1.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      37  M1  POL 1        2.0     1.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      38  M1  POL 1        2.0     1.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      39  M1  POL 1        2.0     2.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      40  M1  POL 1        3.0     2.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      41  M1  POL 1        2.0     3.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      42  M1  POL 1        2.0     2.0     5.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      43  M1  POL 1        3.0     1.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      44  M1  POL 1        3.0     2.0     4.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      45  M1  POL 1        3.0     1.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      46  M1  POL 1        3.0     2.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      47  M1  POL 1        2.0     2.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      48  M1  POL 1        1.0     2.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      49  M1  POL 1        2.0     3.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      50  M1  POL 1        3.0     3.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      51  M1  POL 1        2.0     3.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      52  M1  POL 1        2.0     2.0     3.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      53  M1  POL 1        1.0     3.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      54  M1  POL 1        2.0     2.0     1.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      55  M1  POL 1        1.0     1.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      56  M1  POL 1        1.0     2.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      57  M1  POL 1        0.0     3.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      58  M1  POL 1        0.0     2.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      59  M1  POL 1        1.0     1.0     1.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      60  M1  POL 1        0.0     2.0     1.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      61  M1  POL 1        0.0     1.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      62  M1  POL 1        1.0     2.0     1.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      63  M1  POL 1        2.0     1.0     2.0   1.0   1.0         MM
ATOM      64  M1  POL 1        2.0     1.0     1.0   1.0   1.0         MM
CONECT    1    2
CONECT    2    3
CONECT    3    4
CONECT    4    5
CONECT    5    6
CONECT    6    7
CONECT    7    8
CONECT    8    9
CONECT    9   10
CONECT   10   11
CONECT   11   12
CONECT   12   13
CONECT   13   14
CONECT   14   15
CONECT   15   16
CONECT   16   17
CONECT   17   18
CONECT   18   19
CONECT   19   20
CONECT   20   21
CONECT   21   22
CONECT   22   23
CONECT   23   24
CONECT   24   25
CONECT   25   26
CONECT   26   27
CONECT   27   28
CONECT   28   29
CONECT   29   30
CONECT   30   31
CONECT   31   32
CONECT   32   33
CONECT   33   34
CONECT   34   35
CONECT   35   36
CONECT   36   37
CONECT   37   38
CONECT   38   39
CONECT   39   40
CONECT   40   41
CONECT   41   42
CONECT   42   43
CONECT   43   44
CONECT   44   45
CONECT   45   46
CONECT   46   47
CONECT   47   48
CONECT   48   49
CONECT   49   50
CONECT   50   51
CONECT   51   52
CONECT   52   53
CONECT   53   54
CONECT   54   55
CONECT   55   56
CONECT   56   57
CONECT   57   58
CONECT   58   59
CONECT   59   60
CONECT   60   61
CONECT   61   62
CONECT   62   63
CONECT   63   64
```

When I view this PDB using VMD, I see the following image:
[image]

I do not understand why I see this perfectly connected web of particles, when all I want is for each consecutive particle to be connected. How should I go about solving this visualization issue?

Comment: check the units, if you use the wrong ones, meaning all the atoms are actually very close to each other, then the program will think every atom is bonded to every other atom. I believe VMD calculates bonds based on distance and rules of thumb. I would try multiplying the coordinates by 10, and viewing again? Actually, I see you have the connect record... I don't know if VMD ignores the connect record or not.

Comment: Was B.Kelly's comment helpful?

Comment: @megamence If the pdb contains CONECT records at the end, you can see the bonds as per the CONECT records. Currently, VMD is using its built-in code to predict the bonds and showing it to you. You can turn off this feature by using the command `autobonds off`. Run this command in the tkconsole `mol new XXX.pdb autobonds off`

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that I was using the dynamic bonds setting in VMD. The solution to this is to simply change up how bonds are calculated in VMD.